# org.kordamp.ikonli icons issues

Tags: java, javafx, java-17, module-info

I have simpe **javafx modular app** using **JDK 17**

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <junit.version>5.8.2</junit.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.kordamp.ikonli</groupId>
            <artifactId>ikonli-javafx</artifactId>
            <version>12.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>17.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>17.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.dlsc.formsfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>formsfx-core</artifactId>
            <version>11.5.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.10.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>17</source>
                    <target>17</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.8</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- Default configuration for running with: mvn clean javafx:run -->
                        <id>default-cli</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <mainClass>com.example.demo/com.example.demo.HelloApplication</mainClass>
                            <launcher>app</launcher>
                            <jlinkZipName>app</jlinkZipName>
                            <jlinkImageName>app</jlinkImageName>
                            <noManPages>true</noManPages>
                            <stripDebug>true</stripDebug>
                            <noHeaderFiles>true</noHeaderFiles>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**module-info.java**

```
module com.example.demo {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;

    requires com.dlsc.formsfx;
    requires org.kordamp.ikonli.javafx;
    requires org.kordamp.ikonli.core;

    opens com.example.demo to javafx.fxml;
    exports com.example.demo;
}
```

**hello-view.fxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import org.kordamp.ikonli.javafx.FontIcon?>
<VBox alignment="CENTER" spacing="20.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
      fx:controller="com.example.demo.HelloController">
    <padding>
        <Insets bottom="20.0" left="20.0" right="20.0" top="20.0"/>
    </padding>
    <FontIcon iconColor="#077483" iconLiteral="fab-shopify" iconSize="40" selectionEnd="1"
              selectionStart="1"/>

    <Label fx:id="welcomeText"/>
    <Button text="Hello!" onAction="#onHelloButtonClick"/>
</VBox>
```

I get AN error when running application

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot resolve 'fab-shopify'
    at org.kordamp.ikonli.core@12.3.1/org.kordamp.ikonli.AbstractIkonResolver.resolve(AbstractIkonResolver.java:61)
    at org.kordamp.ikonli.javafx@12.3.1/org.kordamp.ikonli.javafx.IkonResolver.resolve(IkonResolver.java:73)
    at org.kordamp.ikonli.javafx@12.3.1/org.kordamp.ikonli.javafx.FontIcon.setIconLiteral(FontIcon.java:251)
    ... 33 more
Exception running application com.example.demo.HelloApplication
```

If I remove module-info.java it works.

How can I resolve it?

Comment: Here is the source for resolver [line 61](https://github.com/kordamp/ikonli/blob/master/core/ikonli-core/src/main/java/org/kordamp/ikonli/AbstractIkonResolver.java#L61).  You can see later in the source that the resolver is [module aware](https://github.com/kordamp/ikonli/blob/master/core/ikonli-core/src/main/java/org/kordamp/ikonli/AbstractIkonResolver.java#L87).

Comment: `fab-shopify` is in [FontAwesome5](https://kordamp.org/ikonli/#_fontawesome5_latest) under [Brands](https://kordamp.org/ikonli/cheat-sheet-fontawesome5.html).  To use it, you need to depend on `<artifactId>ikonli-fontawesome5-pack</artifactId>` and require `org.kordamp.ikonli.fontawesome5`. I don’t see that you do that.  This is documented in [2.2.1 installing](https://kordamp.org/ikonli/#_javafx).

Comment: Thanks @jewelsea . You are very right. fontawesome5 was missing from the dependecy

Answer (score 2):

I included the dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.kordamp.ikonli</groupId>
    <artifactId>ikonli-fontawesome5-pack</artifactId>
    <version>12.2.0</version>
 </dependency>
```

which solved the problem.